# Unwanted dangle errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

As shown in the image is there any possibilities to avoid unwanted dangle errors in arcgis ?!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLTLH.jpg):[image]

Update: As you can see in the image above, the four red ones which are close to each other have been determined as dangle errors in ArcGIS, but they are not. They are just dead-end alleys, for example. How to force ArcGIS not to determine that as errors?

Comment: You need to add more information to your question or it risks being closed.  How is ArcGIS to know what is an error and what is not?  In the topology toolset, you can easily flag a dangle as not an error.  You just have to go through each one manually.  Please edit your question to contain as much information as possible.

Comment: you can flag unwanted errors as exceptions.

Comment: I am having 40000 errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - if you have a Standard or Advanced level license of ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop then you can use the **[Extend Line (Editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000004000000)** tool to extend them (with a large value for the length parameter) until they meet another line.  You may have to "encircle" your existing data to ensure that a line is always reached.

However, I am not at all sure that this is what you really want to do, so if not, some more details in your Question about your precise requirements and constraints would be worthwhile.

Comment: My tolerance is 0.000000009.. What I have drawn is colony roads. There may be end nodes. How to find out exact dangle error so that we can extend or trim !!

Comment: @Vikram You can edit your Question to revise it with additional details.  My advice would be to zoom in much closer to one of a few dangles and provide considerable more text to describe exactly what it is that you are asking.  About a paragraph is normally considered minimal but in this case you may need more.

Comment: @ PolyGeo I have updated my post !!